# React-router : conditionally redirect at render time

Tags: reactjs, react-router-dom

So I have this basic component `<Redirectable />`:

```
import React from 'react';
import {
  useParams,
  useHistory,
  Redirect,
} from 'react-router-dom';

export default () => {
  const history = useHistory();
  const {id} = useParams();

  if (!checkMyId(id) {
    // invalid ID, go back home
    history.push('/');
  }
  return <p>Hey {id}</p>
}
```

But I get the following error:

```
Warning: Cannot update during an existing state transition (such as within `render`). Render methods should be a pure function of props and state.
```

I also tried: `<Redirect push to="/" />`, but same error.

What's the correct way to handle this? I read about `onEnter` callback at `<Router />` level, but as far as I'm concerned, the check should happen at `<Redirectable />` level.

There should be a solution, shouldn't it? I don't feel like I'm doing something completely anti-react-pattern, am I?

Comment: I think you are pushing to history object in the render method which causes `useHistory` to be called again... You can put it in a `useEffect`.

Answer (score 0):

This seems to do the trick. I was not able to find any documentation as to why this occures. All I was able to find was different examples with callbacks but this solved it for me.

```
import React from 'react';
import {
  useParams,
  useHistory,
  Redirect,
} from 'react-router-dom';

const MyComponent = () => {
  const history = useHistory();
  const {id} = useParams();

  if (!checkMyId(id) {
    // invalid ID, go back home
    history.push('/');
  }
  return <p>Hey {id}</p>
}
export default MyComponent;
```

It seems that react may recognize `export default () => {` as a pure component and so side effects are prohibited.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it seems to me you are written the component in a anti pattern way. Can you please update like below:

```
const Rediractabke = () => {
        const history = useHistory();
        const {id} = useParams();

        if (!checkMyId(id) {
             // invalid ID, go back home
             history.push('/');
         }
         return <p>Hey {id}</p>
  }

  export default as Redirectable;
```

Answer (score 0):

@c0m1t was right, the solution was to use `useEffect`:

```
import React, {useEffect} from 'react';
import {
  useParams,
  useHistory,
  Redirect,
} from 'react-router-dom';

export default () => {
  const history = useHistory();
  const {id} = useParams();

  useEffect(() => {
    if (!checkMyId(id) {
      // invalid ID, go back home
      history.push('/');
    }
  })

  return <p>Hey {id}</p>
}
```